# what is the value of a + b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to find $a+b$, without find the values of $a$ and $b$ first?

> If $4(a – 3) – 2(b + 5) = 14$ and $5b – a = 0$, what is the value of $a + b$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the two equations, and get $3a+3b-12-10=14$

Comment: So simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have : 
5b – a = 0 and 4(a – 3) – 2(b + 5) = 14

Equation 1:
    5b-a=0
=>  a=5b

Adding b on both sides,

=>  a+b=6b -Eq. 3

Equation 2: 
    4a - 12 - 2b -10 =14
=>  4a - 2b = 14+10+12
=>  2a - b = 7+5+6
=>  2a - b = 18
=>  2a - 18 = b

Adding 2b on both sides,

=>  2 (a + b) -18 = 3b

Multiplying 2 on both sides,
    4 (a + b) - 36 = 6b
    4 (a + b) - 6b = 36

From Eq. 3

4(a + b) - (a + b)=36
3(a + b) = 36

Hence a + b = 12

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can.  But should you?

Suppose:

$ma + nb = c;$

$xa+yb=d$

then

$m(a+b) + (n-m)b = c;$

$x(a+b) + (y-x)b = d$

if $n = m$ you already had $ma+nb = ma + mb = m(a+b) = c$ so we can assume $n \ne m$ and likewise $x \ne y$.  We continue:

$\frac{m}{n-m}(a+b) + b = \frac c{n-m};$

$\frac{-x}{y-x}(a+b) - b = \frac{-d}{y-x}$

Combine:

$(\frac{m}{n-m}-\frac{x}{y-x})(a + b) = \frac{c}{n-m} - \frac{d}{y-x}$

If $\frac{m}{n-m}-\frac{x}{y-x} = 0$ then.. well, that means the two original equations were multiples of each other and you can *not* get anywhere this way.  However if $\frac{m}{n-m}-\frac{x}{y-x} \ne 0$ we *CAN* get

$a + b = \frac{\frac{c}{n-m} - \frac{d}{y-x}}{\frac{m}{n-m}-\frac{x}{y-x}}$

$=\frac{\frac{c(y-x)}{n-m} - d}{\frac{m(y-x)}{n-m}-x}$

$=\frac{c(y-x) - d(n-m)}{m(y-x)-x(n-m)}$

The question is... is it worth doing?  And that depends.  In your example it is easy---

$4(a–3)–2(b+5)=14\implies 4a - 2b=36$ and $5b–a=0$ will mean $(4a - 2b) + (5b -a) = 36+0$ which means $3(a+b) = 36$ and $a + b = 12$.

--- but my equations in general?  Doable but... maybe not worth the trouble.

====

Or another way to think of it:

$ma + nb = c$

$xa + yb = d$

Let $U = a + b$ so

$mU + (n-m)b = c$

$xU + (y-x)b = d$.

Put $b$ in terms of $U$.  [$b = \frac{c - mU}{n-m}$].  Plug into the other equation [$xU + (y-x)\frac{c - mU}{n-m}$] and solve for $U$.

Example:

$4(a–3)–2(b+5)=14$ and $5b–a=0$

Let $U = a + b$ so

$4(U - b - 3) - 2(b + 5) = 14$

$4U -4b - 12 - 2b - 10 = 14$

$4U - 6b = 36$

and

$5b - U + b = 0$

$6b - U = 0$

Therefore $b = U/6$ and $4U - 6b =4U - 6U/6 = 4U - U = 3U = 36$.  So $U = a + b = 12$.

.